# how to set SwitchPreference toggle because marshmallow only show the On OFF text but not display toggle

Tags: java, android, android-preferences, android-switch

my app SwitchPreference  only show the ON or OFF text But not display toggle how to show toggle in my application any one help me. i tried but the toggle is not display
[only show text Not display Toggle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wC0bo.jpg)

Comment: Can you post the contents of your preference screen XML?

Comment: it is my preference screen  <SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/prevent_uninstall"
        android:key="prevent_uninstall_checkbox_keypad"
        android:title="@string/pref_title_prevent_uninstall"/>